# Periodic events with duration

Tags: highcharts, duration

I need to show on graph duration of periodic events. For example user with ID 1 is calling to user with ID 2 at 10:00 AM and they are speaking 5 minutes. Then he is calling him again at 2:00PM and they are speaking 2 minutes. So this events are happening periodically and I need to show them on the graph as horizontal bars. They should look something like that: User 1: [  5min  ][ 2min ][ ... ][ ... ]

I've almost achieved what I want except that I can't find the way to show time at X axis. The X axis should show time with 30 minutes interval.

Here is my configuration:

```
title: null,
chart: {
   type: 'bar',
   backgroundColor: '#F9F9F9',
   plotBackgroundColor: '#F9F9F9',
   borderColor: '#F9F9F9',
   borderWidth: 1,
   animation: 0
},
legend: {
   enabled: false
},  
series: [
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'red'}          ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'blue'}         ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'transparent'}  ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'red'}          ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'transparent'}  ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'red'}          ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'blue'}         ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'red'}          ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'transparent'}  ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'red'}          ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'transparent'}  ] },
   { data: [{ y:1, color: 'red'}          ] }
],
xAxis: {
   categories: ['User 1']
},
yAxis: {
   allowDecimals: false,
   min: 0,
   type: '',
   title: {
      text: 'Time'
   },
   stackLabels: {
      enabled: false
   }  
}, 
plotOptions: {
   bar: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
   },
   borderWidth: 0
}
```

Here is demonstration of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitrykislichenko/SjdR5/

Comment: Could you attached a mockup of your concept? It is something like gantt? http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart

Comment: Sebastian, thank you for link. This seems to be quite similar to what I want to achieve. Here is mockup of the concept http://jsfiddle.net/dimitrykislichenko/SjdR5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using columnrange series with axis `type: 'datetime'`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/SjdR5/2/

Note requires change in series object:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        x: 0,
        low: Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1, 10, 53),
        high: Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1, 10, 59),
        color: 'red'
    },{
        x: 0,
        low: Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1, 12, 12),
        high: Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1, 12, 17),
        color: 'red'
    },{
        x: 0,
        low: Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1, 16, 35),
        high: Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1, 16, 55),
        color: 'red'
    }]
}],
```

- `x:0`  -it's category index ( 0 = User 1 )
- `low` and `high` is like from and to for time
- `color` is just color of bar ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I wanted!